# Extract google search snippets only using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the google search result snippets for a query.i am using BeautifulSoup in Python. My code is as follows:

```
question = "Where is Tajmahal?"
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
query = question
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
url = "http://www.google.com/search?%s&"+query 
page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

I dont know how to proceed from here. I dont know in which tag the google search snippets are stored. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the end of your code:

```
google_html = open('google.html', 'w')
google_html.write(str(soup.prettify()))
google_html.close()
```

Then go look at the html to figure out which tags you're looking for.  Your question is vague as to what exactly you want to get and also you may notice when you look in the file that prints that it may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and more visual way to locate and get `CSS` selectors is to use the [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension by clicking the desired element in your browser and.

Code to extract snippets from one page of search results:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'Where is Tajmahal?'}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=',
                    headers=headers,
                    params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for snippets in soup.select('.aCOpRe span'):
  snippet = snippets.text
  print(f'{snippet}\n'
```

Part of the output:

```
The Taj Mahal (/ˌtɑːdʒ məˈhɑːl, ˌtɑːʒ-/; lit. 'Crown of the Palace', [taːdʒ ˈmɛːɦ(ə)l]), originally the Rauza-i-munawwara is an ivory-white marble ...

Taj Mahal, also spelled Tadj Mahall, mausoleum complex in Agra, western Uttar Pradesh state, northern India. The Taj Mahal was built by the Mughal emperor ...

The Taj Mahal is located on the right bank of the Yamuna River in a vast Mughal garden that encompasses nearly 17 hectares, in the Agra District in Uttar Pradesh.
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main differences are that you don't have to think about solving CAPTCHA if it occurs, going through HTML or inline Javascript code to find what you're looking for, and you get a JSON output.

Code to integrate:

```py
m serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Where is Tajmahal?",
  "api_key": os.getenv('API_KEY')
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  print(f"{result['snippet']}\n")
```

Part of the output:

```
The Taj Mahal (/ˌtɑːdʒ məˈhɑːl, ˌtɑːʒ-/; lit. 'Crown of the Palace', [taːdʒ ˈmɛːɦ(ə)l]), originally the Rauza-i-munawwara is an ivory-white marble ...

Taj Mahal, also spelled Tadj Mahall, mausoleum complex in Agra, western Uttar Pradesh state, northern India. The Taj Mahal was built by the Mughal emperor ...

The Taj Mahal is located on the right bank of the Yamuna River in a vast Mughal garden that encompasses nearly 17 hectares, in the Agra District in Uttar Pradesh.
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.